# Synchronized objects removes from a reverse list [JList - SWING]

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlist

I'm having troubles managing an ArrayList using a custom AbstractListModel.
Here's is my model:

TradesListModel.class

```
package window;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;

import main.Trade;

public class TradesListModel extends AbstractListModel<Object>{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ArrayList<Trade> trades;

    public TradesListModel(){
        trades = new ArrayList<Trade>();
    }

    public void add(Trade trade){
        trades.add(0, trade);
        this.fireIntervalAdded(this, 0, 1);
    }

    public void remove(){
        trades.remove(trades.size()-1);
        this.fireIntervalRemoved(this, trades.size(), trades.size());
    }

    public void clear(){
        trades.clear();
        this.fireIntervalRemoved(this, 0, trades.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return trades.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        return trades.get(index);
    }

}
```

As you can see every object is added to the top of my list by three threads working in concurrency. Every thread adds new objects by calling a method in my main class:

```
public void addTrade(Trade trade){
            trades.add(trade);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myModel.add(trade);
                }

            });
}
```

I have another `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` that every 30 seconds call the method of my main class `remove()`to remove objects from the list handled by my custom model:

```
public boolean updateTrades(){
     Iterator<Trade> it = trades.iterator();
     try {
        synchronized(this){
            index = 0;
            while(it.hasNext()){
                Trade current = it.next();
                if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()-current.getTime())>TIME){
                    it.remove();
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            lm.remove(index);
                        }
                    });
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     return false;
 }
```

The `trades` list is equal to the `trades` list into the model.
What I've done is print the index value passed to the model but it doesn't correspond to the index into the main class as I get this exception multiple times:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -6
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:495)
at window.TradesListModel.remove(TradesListModel.java:28)
at main.TradeFinder$2.run(TradeFinder.java:119)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

`TradeFinder` is my main class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the following example: `updateTrades` was called when there are three trades in the list: `[t0, t1, t2]` and all of them should be removed.

In this case you will call `lm.remove` method three times: with indices `0`, `1`, and `2`. After the first the list will contain `[t1, t2]`, and after the second: `[t2]`. When you call it third time, there is no element with index `2`, so you'll get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To fix it, just call `lm.remove(0)` three times. This will remove first three elements, as expected.

Comment: The _i_-th (zero-based) last element of the list has index `size-i-1`, so you should add `-1` to `trades.remove(trades.size()-index);` line.

Comment: Notice, that ranges for `fireIntervalAdded` and `fireIntervalRemoved` are inconsistent. For example, you add elements to the start of the list, while `fireIntervalAdded` reports that element is added to end. This may result in buggy UI redraws.

Comment: anyway the updateTrades method is called only by the scheduledExecutor thread

Comment: how can I fix the fireIntervalAdded and fireIntervalRemoved?

Comment: `this.fireIntervalAdded(this, 0, 1);` and `this.fireIntervalRemoved(this, trades.size() - index, trades.size() - index);` (notice, that the element was removed on the previous line, so `-1` is not needed any more).

Comment: I edited the model class in the first post. Thank you so much for your help.